# EF Core migration error with .NET Core Web API in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a solution with two projects inside Visual Studio Code:

- `webapi` project called Sample.API
- `classlib` project called Sample.Data

In Sample.Data, I have these packages installed:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

After creating a DbContext for a simple model and specifying the connection string, I run into the following error when executing this command (Inside the Sample.Data folder):

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration`

```
Startup project 'Sample.Data.csproj' targets framework '.NETStandard'.
There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it can't be executed directly.
To use the Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools with this project, add an executable project
targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework that references this project, and set it as the startup project
using --startup-project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Core or .NET Framework...
```

If this was Visual Studio, I would set the WebAPI project as the startup project. But I'm using VS Code.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the option `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --startup-project Sample.API.csproj` ? This should set the project as the startup [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#using-the-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sea_ocean ... You have to specify the startup project:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationOne --startup-project ../Sample.API/Sample.API.csproj
```

and then

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../Sample.API/Sample.API.csproj
```

You also need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design to the startup project